# Scrolling with mouse scroll wheel doesn't trigger jQuery hover or mouseover

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover

I have an unordered list with each list item background changing color when the mouse hovers over it. If the mouse does not move and the scroll wheel is scrolled down the cursor floats above different list items but the hover class through jQuery is not triggered. Why is this? How do I solve the problem?

Here is the code.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.jMapping =  {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var jMap,
          pointToMoveTo,
          data,
          bounds,
          icon,
          $el;

      $('#map').height(200).jMapping({
        category_icon_options: {
          'default': {color: '#7CDF65'}
        }
      });

      jMap = $('#map').data('jMapping');
      bounds = jMap.getBounds();

      $.each(jMap.gmarkers, function(id, marker){  

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
          $('#nid-' + id).addClass('hover');
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
          $('#nid-' + id).removeClass('hover');
        });
      });


      $("#map-side-bar li").mouseenter(function() {

        $el = $(this);
        data = $el.data('jmapping');

        if (!$el.hasClass("hover")) {
          $el.addClass("hover");

          jMap.gmarkers[data.id].styleIcon.set("color", "#017DC3"); 
          pointToMoveTo = $.jMapping.makeGLatLng(data.point);
          jMap.map.panTo(pointToMoveTo);
        }
      }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("#map-side-bar li").removeClass("hover");
        jMap.gmarkers[data.id].styleIcon.set("color", "#7CDF65");    
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [mousewheel plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) by Brandon Aaron:

> A jQuery plugin that adds
>   cross-browser mouse wheel support.

```
// using bind
$('#my_elem').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    console.log(delta);
});

// using the event helper
$('#my_elem').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    console.log(delta);
});
```

Comment: This jQuery plugin just uses the mousewheel event. document.getElemmentById('thing').onmousewheel = yourFunc does the trick too. I only tested in chrome

Comment: The plugin standardises the delta you'll get back from mousewheel events on different browsers / platforms.

Comment: If you goal is to invoke a hover action when an item is scrolled over, the raw mousewheel event is best for webkit. Many UIs have no concern for the delta (facebook ticker, gmail offline)

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this,  might fix the issue.

[how to highlight rows in a table on mouse hover ?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-highlight-rows-in-a-table-on-mouse-hover/)